# Spring Boot Tomcat deployment

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am having issue with deploying spring boot application in Tomcat 8. I am getting the error below while starting application.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

our webinitializer

```
public class SpringWebMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

    return new Class[]{SecurityConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

     return new Class[] {WebMvcConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}}
```

Comment: Really not able to understand the issue with the post. leave a message while down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem by changing my web fertilizer to

```
public class SpringWebMvcInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  {
// nothing here 
}
```

reference - 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/